# Acer Travelmate P614 speakers don't work on Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, kubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa, speakers

I have installed Kubuntu 20.04 on an Acer Travelmate P614. The speakers of the notebook don't work, though the headphones work. The microphone also works. From the previous Windows installation I also know, that the speakers can work. The volume control(pulseaudio) indicates that a sound stream is written into the Speaker output device, which is not muted and has finite volume set. On the alsamixer, the speaker is also not muted and a finite volume is set.

I have once removed and reinstalled alsa-base and pulse audio and applied "alsa force-reload". However, after also toggling some switches in /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output-lineout.conf according to a [blog](https://leimao.github.io/blog/Ubuntu-No-Sound-Fix/), even the headphone was not working after reboot, temporarily.

What can I do?

```
inxi -SMA
System:    Host: garfield Kernel: 5.4.0-42-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.18.5 
           Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: Acer product: TravelMate P614-51-G2 v: V1.06 serial: <superuser/root required> 
           Mobo: CML model: Piano_CM v: V1.06 serial: <superuser/root required> UEFI: Insyde v: 1.06 date: 02/25/2020 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel driver: sof-audio-pci 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-42-generic 

lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9b61 (rev 0c)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 0c)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Thermal Subsytem
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 02ed
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 02ef
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9462
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Serial IO I2C Host Controller
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Serial IO I2C Host Controller
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Management Engine Interface
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation Device 02d7
00:19.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 02c5
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 02b4 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 0284
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device 02c8
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 02a3
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake SPI (flash) Controller
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (6) I219-LM
01:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06)
02:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06)
02:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06)
02:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06)
03:00.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 NHI [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06)
3a:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I have the very same problem but on Arch Linux with Plasam KDE Desktop Environment. It is probably not a distribution related problem. Here is a link to the discussion on Arch Linux Forums: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=256592

And here is the link to the alsa-devel mailing lsit discussion: https://www.spinics.net/lists/alsa-devel/msg111034.html

I have tested a lot of different options as suggested by the alsa-mailing list answers to my question but unfortunately I have not found any solution yet.

My tests included settings through hdajackretask and some GPIO settings through hda-verb.

It seams like a bug coming from wrong BIOS set-up at boot. It would be possible to use some quirks to fix it possibly, but I am not that good to try out myself.

Hope, that someone will find a solution to this.

Best